# Reg: Remote Service

Tags: android, service

Can any one provide sample Remote service example. I want it like two different application. One application should contain service. Another application should use that service.
Thanks in adv....

Comment: There are many different ways to provide a remote service.  There is SOAP, RPC, REST, etc.  Do you have any preferences?  What languages/toolkits are you using?

Comment: Is the service running on Android ? or is it running on a server ?
If it is on a server what kind of server ?
Can you give us more details ?
I also deleted your contact info from the post, all questions are answered here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [client](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient/) and here is the [service](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteService/). Here is the [book](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/) that talks about them. :-)

Comment: Here is another client: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/19-RemoteService/Patchy/ And here is another service: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/19-RemoteService/TMonitor/ And here is the book that talks about those: http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/

Answer (score 0):

All you need comes from Android sample projects. Here is [one](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.html).